# Why doesn't kube-proxy route traffic to another worker node?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

I've deployed several different services and always get the same error.

The service is reachable on the node port from the machine where the pod is running. On the two other nodes I get timeouts.

The kube-proxy is running on all worker nodes and I can see in the logfiles from kube-proxy that the service port was added and the node port was opened.
In this case I've deployed the stars demo from calico

Kube-proxy log output:

```
Mar 11 10:25:10 kuben1 kube-proxy[659]: I0311 10:25:10.229458     659 service.go:309] Adding new service port "management-ui/management-ui:" at 10.32.0.133:9001/TCP
Mar 11 10:25:10 kuben1 kube-proxy[659]: I0311 10:25:10.257483     659 proxier.go:1427] Opened local port "nodePort for management-ui/management-ui:" (:30002/tcp)
```

The kube-proxy is listening on the port 30002

```
root@kuben1:/tmp# netstat -lanp | grep 30002
tcp6       0      0 :::30002                :::*                    LISTEN      659/kube-proxy
```

There are also some iptable rules defined:

```
root@kuben1:/tmp# iptables -L -t nat | grep management-ui
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* management-ui/management-ui: */ tcp dpt:30002
KUBE-SVC-MIYW5L3VT4JVLCIZ  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* management-ui/management-ui: */ tcp dpt:30002
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  tcp  -- !10.200.0.0/16        10.32.0.133          /* management-ui/management-ui: cluster IP */ tcp dpt:9001
KUBE-SVC-MIYW5L3VT4JVLCIZ  tcp  --  anywhere             10.32.0.133          /* management-ui/management-ui: cluster IP */ tcp dpt:9001
```

The interesting part is that I can reach the service IP from any worker node

```
root@kubem1:/tmp# kubectl get svc -n management-ui
NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
management-ui   NodePort   10.32.0.133   <none>        9001:30002/TCP   52m
```

The service IP/port can be accessed from any worker node if I do a "curl http://10.32.0.133:9001"

I don't understand why kube-proxy does not "route" this properly...
Has anyone a hint where I can find the error?

---

Here some cluster specs:

This is a hand build cluster inspired by Kelsey Hightower's "kubernetes the hard way" guide.

- 6 Nodes (3 master: 3 worker) local vms
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- K8s: v1.13.0
- Docker: 18.9.3
- Cni: calico

Component status on the master nodes looks okay

```
root@kubem1:/tmp# kubectl get componentstatus
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE             ERROR
controller-manager   Healthy   ok                  
scheduler            Healthy   ok                  
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true"}   
etcd-1               Healthy   {"health":"true"}   
etcd-2               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
```

The worker nodes are looking okay if I trust kubectl

```
root@kubem1:/tmp# kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kuben1   Ready    <none>   39d   v1.13.0   192.168.178.77   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-46-generic   docker://18.9.3
kuben2   Ready    <none>   39d   v1.13.0   192.168.178.78   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-46-generic   docker://18.9.3
kuben3   Ready    <none>   39d   v1.13.0   192.168.178.79   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-46-generic   docker://18.9.3
```

As asked by P Ekambaram:

```
root@kubem1:/tmp# kubectl get po -n kube-system
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-node-bgjdg                      1/1     Running   5          40d
calico-node-nwkqw                      1/1     Running   5          40d
calico-node-vrwn4                      1/1     Running   5          40d
coredns-69cbb76ff8-fpssw               1/1     Running   5          40d
coredns-69cbb76ff8-tm6r8               1/1     Running   5          40d
kubernetes-dashboard-57df4db6b-2xrmb   1/1     Running   5          40d
```

Comment: Share output from kubectl get po -n kube-system

Comment: I've added the output from "kubectl get po -n kube-system"

Comment: @PEkambaram: I think i've found the error but not a nice solution yet... If i allow forwarding with the following cmd "iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT" everything works well. This was an error with docker versions newer 1.13.x and should be fixed in k8s version 1.8 [Merge Request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/52569). I've configured kube-proxy with "--cluster-cidr=10.105.0.0/24" but it doesn't have any effect on my problem...

Comment: Yes, I too came across this issue with Docker 1.13

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution for my "Problem".
This behavior was caused by a change in Docker v1.13.x and the issue was fixed in kubernetes with version 1.8.

The easy solution was to change the forward rules via iptables.
Run the following cmd on all worker nodes: "iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT"

To fix it the right way i had to tell the kube-proxy the cidr for the pods.
Theoretical that could be solved in two ways:

- Add "--cluster-cidr=10.0.0.0/16" as argument to the kube-proxy command line(in my case  in the systemd service file)
- Add 'clusterCIDR: "10.0.0.0/16"' to the kubeconfig file for kube-proxy

In my case the cmd line argument doesn't had any effect.
As i've added the line to my kubeconfig file and restarted the kube-proxy on all worker nodes everything works well.

Here is the github merge request for this "FORWARD" issue: [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/52569)